# New Window Times Out After Launching

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, session-timeout

I need a new window, when launched, to be closed after a set time.

Here's what I'm using to launch a new window.

```
<a href='javascript:window.open("https://mylinehere.com","contestrules", "menubar=0,resizable=0,width=800,height=800");'><img src="path/image.png"></a>
```

This window needs to timeout after a certain amount of time post launch. Is this possible with some js magic? I'm limited to JS v1.7.

Thanks.

Comment: so `setTimeout` is what you need.

Comment: Only if the opened window closes itself. Use a proper click-handler function, store a reference to the opened window, and use `setTimeout` to close the window later.

Comment: @jbman223 I don't have access to the new window being launched. Any way to pass the script?

Comment: No need, the answer below will work. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout and close()

```
function openAndClose() {
    var popup_window = window.open("");
    window.seTimeout( function () {
        if (popup_window && !popup_window.closed)
            popup_window.close();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```